# Saving data from database into associative array with counting up - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop, while-loop

I would like to sort data from my database. I want to use associative arrays so it can be sorted the best.

I get all the data from a database, as said above. By doing $row['manufacturer'] I'll get some data like the following:

```
motorola
sony
motorola
google
samsung
lg
samsung
```

I would like it to be saved like this in the array: (order is not important, although alphabetically is preferred)

```
"motorola" => 2
"sony" => 1
"google" => 1
"samsung" => 2
"lg" => 1
```

I tried it by doing this, but it just didn't work and caused my web host to clean the logs, as it caused almost 2 gigs of log files.

The code I wrote to save it

```
$manufacturers = array();

//$row are the rows from my database. I will not add them, but by doing $row['manufacturer'] you'll get some brands like google, motorola, etc.
while($row = $resultSelect->fetch_assoc()) {

  for ($i = 0; $i < $manufacturers; $i++) {
    $alreadyEntered = 0;
    if ($manufacturers[$i] == $row['manufacturer']) $alreadyEntered = 1;
    if ($alreadyEntered == 0) {
        $manufacturers[$row['manufacturer']] = 1;
    } else {
        $manufacturers[$row['manufacturer']] += 1;
    }

    //It caused huge logs, so I decided to break on 50.
    if ($i > 50) {
        break;
    }
  }
}

//Dump it :) to see if it worked
var_dump($manufacturers);
```

I have no idea how I can make it work. I tried searching on Google and SO for setting values in associative arrays, but nothing worked.

**EDIT:**

My rows:

[image]

Comment: So your table have multiple row with same  "manufacture" and now you want to sort it by counting it? You could do that just by using SQL query

Comment: @AfifZafri Yes I have multiple rows and yes I would like to sort it by counting. If I could do it using SQL, how could I do that? I also edited the post so you can see the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it through SQL query. 
Using the `count` and `group by` query.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as total
FROM manufactures
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

`name` is your manufactures name column. `manufactures` is your table name.

**Example PHP code:**

```
$sql="SELECT name, COUNT(*) as total
FROM manufactures
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "Name: ". $row['name'] . " Total: ". $row['total'] . "<br>";
}
```

**Brief explanation:**

What the query will do is that it will `select all` manufactures name, and `count` them. By in the same time, it will `group` together the names, which means, multiple same name will be grouped together, and counted together. Finally `order by name asc` is used to sort the result alphabetically in ascending order (A->Z).

Comment: Great. I have edited the answer to sort the result alphabetically

Comment: Great, thanks for giving me an even more efficient way!

Comment: @Jason I have updated the answer. set the count result as a "total" column name, and then you can access it. Look at my example PHP code